# Inserting into array within loop

Tags: xml, f#, f#-data

I am trying to create an array of available longitude and latitude pairs, which are returned in `XML`. I am using `F# Data` to achieve it, this is what I have so far.

```
// #r @"load data dll"

open FSharp.Data

type Html = XmlProvider<"<my-url>", Global=true>
let html = Html.GetSample()

// Create an availableList array, so that it would have pairs of available Latitude and Longitude
let availableList = Array.create

let getCoordinates available = 
  for item in html.Objects do
    if item.StatusParkPlace = available then
      // If true, push item.Latitude and item.Longitude into availableList 

let main = 
  getCoordinates true

main
```

I am aware, that `array` initialization on line #9 is incorrect, I am also aware that conditional `if` statement on line #13 is not finished. I am able to print out pairs on line #14 as follows, but I cannot see how that is useful for me:

```
printfn "%A - %A" item.Latitude item.Longitude
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functional programming try to avoid building up lists by iterating through data and items to a new list. This is the imperative approach and relies on mutating a shared state.

In your example consider doing it this way:

```
let getCoordinates available = 
  html.Objects
  |> Seq.filter (fun item -> item.StatusParkPlace = available)
  |> Seq.toList

let main = 
  let availableList = getCoordinates true
```

It is still the same outcome, building one list from another sequence. But this time you are letting the language deal with the implementation of that, you just supply a function you wish to apply to each item to [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.filter%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) one list into another.

In the above example. `Seq.filter` will perform the loop through `html.Objects` and only return items that match the function into a new sequence. It's then converted into a list (prefer Lists over arrays in F#) that will hold the results. Without the `toList` it would just be a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences) still.

Comment: Thank You, @daveshaw, I should definitely look into sequences. Your provided solution looks much more simpler than what I had, probably that is the beauty of functional programming.

Comment: @Kelb56 - it is indeed :)